# How to show-hide the list under the list on click of button in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

My container code is given below. I am calling it from another component. I have to expand/collapse the list which is present under another list.

```jsx
return this.props.labresult.map(test => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className='Result-list'>
        <li key={test.testId}>
          <div>
            <div className='Result-list__title'>
              <span> {test.testName}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='Flt-rt' >
              <IconButton tooltip="Collapse">
                <ContentRemoveCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton tooltip="Expand">
                <ContentAddCircle />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='Clearfix' />
          <div className='Border-all'>
            {
              test.labresultList.map(result => {
                return (
                  <li key={result.labresultId} >
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <IconButton tooltip="Edit" key={result.labresultId} onClick={() => this.props.editLabResult(result)}>
                          <EditorModeEdit />
                        </IconButton>
                        <span> {result.loincCodeName} &nbsp;</span>          
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span> <b>status:</b> {result.status}</span>
                        <span>   {result.value}{result.uom} </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Clearfix' />
                  </li>
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul >
    </div>
  );
});
```

Now `onClick` of `Collapse` and `Expand` I have to **show/hide** the `test.labresultList`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does my answer below make sense?

Answer (score 3):

First I'd recommend to break the nested divs into their own components as it gets more complex the more nesting there is. I'd even recommend putting the `<li>` tags as their own components and pass down the props.

So it looks more like this:

```
return this.props.labresult.map((test) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className='Result-list'>
                <Test key={test.testId} {...test} />
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and in the `Test` component you can even break apart other child components.

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div className='Result-list__title'>
            <span> {this.props.testName}</span>
        </div>
        {/*----- all other stuff here ------------*/}
        <div className='Border-all'>
           {this._renderLabResults()}
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Ok, back to your original question. There's a few ways to do this:

- If you're using only component state (ie, using `this.state` or `this.setState`) make a `collapsed` boolean state and default it to `false` in the constructor. When a user clicks a button that changes this state you can filter the `test.labresultList` based on the value.
- If you're using a state container like Redux you can use the Redux state and dispatch an action. When a user clicks a button that changes this prop you can filter the `test.labresultList` based on the value in the Redux state that was passed into the component.

For something simple as a `collapsed` boolean prop I'd recommend just using component state. It's specific only to the single component and there's no need to keep this value in the global Redux state. Unless you need it for other reasons.

In the constructor of `Test`:

```
this.state = {
    collapsed: false,
}
```

and when a user clicks a button that switches the collapsed boolean use `setState` like so: `this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed})`

In `_renderLabResults()` use a conditional to render the appropriate child components.

```
_renderLabResults() {
    if (!this.state.collapsed) {
                    // Not collapsed...render the test result here
    }
    return null     // Collapsed...render nothing
}
```